# Not able to figure out the logic of the ouput of this pointer code

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Consider the following c snippet:

```
int main(){
    int *a = (int *)60;
    int *b = (int *)40; 

    cout << a - b; 
    return 0;
}
```

The following code give output as 5. My understanding is `int *a` defines a pointer to memory address of 60, so going by this logic the output should be 20. On outputting the values of `a` and `b`, it gives the hexadecimal representation of 60 (0x3c) and 40 (0x28); still the program prints 5.

Can somebody please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: You only get 20 if `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Got it. It gives how far the memory address are which is 5. as integer takes 4 byte of memory on 64 bit system.

Comment: *"as integer takes 4 byte of memory on 64 bit system"* - usually, and evidently so on your system if it's outputting 5, but that's not mandated by the C++ Standard (i.e. `int` could be larger).  But the point is still that it's reporting the different in multiples of the size of the pointed-to type.